# My Query dont work

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I need help on this problem witch I have been stucked some days. I am running an application, where the idea is to store in a db products with certain attributes, show them on `DataGridView` and edit them if its the case.

I can insert properly the information on db and it stores correctly. Now, when I try to edit them, i call db information from `DataGridView` correctly, and when i edit the information I have this `ERROR MESSAGE:  incorrect syntax near '('`

This is my code, if someone can help me I would be very great-full.

All this is inside the method "Edit":

```
    string constring = "Data Source=MyPC;Initial Catalog=StockCenter;Integrated Security=True";
    string Query = "update MyPC.StockCenter.dbo.Productos set (id_producto='" + this.txtCodigo + "',Marca='" + this.txtMarca.Text + "',Capacidad='" + this.txtCapacidad.Text + "',Proveedor='" + this.cboProveedores.SelectedValue + "',PrecioLista='" + this.txtPrecioLista.Text + "',PrecioVenta'" + this.txtPrecioVenta.Text + "' where id_productos='" + this.txtCodigo.Text + "')";
    SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
    SqlDataReader myReader;
    try
    {
        conDataBase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Edited");
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
```

I belive problem is on String Query.

Comment: What is the actual text of the SQL that's being passed to the database?

Comment: you are missing `=` after `PrecioVenta`.

Comment: Why you enclosed the set and where portion in parenthesis. Remove "(" after SET and ")" in end of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not working because you missed the "=" sign here:
 PrecioVenta'" + this.txtPrecioVenta.Text + "'

So Update it By: PrecioVenta='" + this.txtPrecioVenta.Text + "'

Comment: Yes, that was other error too. 1st i removed the "(" and ")" that i had wrong, then i found out this error u mention. Many thx for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use SqlParameter..
That way you would avoid sql injection attack,enclosing data with `'` or `"` & other issues..

```
String query = "update MyPC.StockCenter.dbo.Productos set id_producto=@id_producto,..."
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id_producto", this.txtCodigo));
//other paramters

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, i will learn use this parameters! Thx!